# Where is the customDomainVerificationId to get domain verification ID in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-dns

I need to verify the ownership of the domain by adding a verification ID as a TXT record with your domain provider. In the left navigation of your app page, click **Resource explorer** under **Development Tools**, then click Go.

In the JSON view of your app's properties, search for **customDomainVerificationId**, and copy its value inside the double quotes. You need this verification ID for the next step.

Issues need your help:

1. There is no **Resource explorer** under **Development Tools**
2. I found the app in the **Resource explorer** by the search bar of the Azure portal (don't even know if it is the one mentioned it above that in the app page). but I CAN'T FIND ANY **customDomainVerificationId** in the Jason File.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the resoure Explorer https://resources.azure.com, in the left navigation, go to subscription > your-subscription > providers > Microsoft.Web > sites
then, you can lookup for the web app by name, to see the JSON view of the app's properties

Answer (score 2):

As @ayzee just said you can find it in  subscription > your-subscription > providers > Microsoft.Web > sites, just to clear it up with some visuals.
[image: azure example]